# Unable to change data in nested objects using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-variable

I am writing a big program as a personal project, and in it i have nested objects. For example World contains multiple environments with each enviroment containing multiple people. What i am trying to do is that i am trying to return the traits of those people from the People class to the Enviroment class to the World class and then to the main program to display said results. I am using multiprocessing to run each People object where traits actively change in it.

The code attached is a smaller version of the problem. `Type1` makes a `Type2` where `Type2` changes its values and then `Type1` values are changed based on the `Type2` changes but `Type1` instance doesn't detect the changes in `Type2`. I tried using locks, manager, values, queues and syncmanagers (all from multiprocessing) and none seemed to work.Is there something obvious i am missing? or is there a different preferred program structure to achieve what i want to do?

My expected output was for `Type1` change it's specific data type values to `Type2` according to the `change()` function in both `Type1` and `Type2`

```
import multiprocessing
import time


class Type1:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.array =[]
        self.dict = {}
        self.text = ""
        self.number = 0
        self.process_dict = {}
        self.type2_dict = {}
        self.num = 0
    
    def start(self):
            new_type = Type2()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_type.change)
            self.process_dict[f"type2{self.num}"] = p
            self.type2_dict[f"type2{self.num}"] = new_type
            self.num += 1
            p.start()
        
    def stop(self):
        while len(self.process_dict) > 0:
            _, process = self.process_dict.popitem()
            process.terminate()
            process.join()

    
    def change(self):
        self.array, self.dict, self.text, self.number = self.type2_dict[f"type2{self.num-1}"].get_data()
            
    def print(self):
        print(self.array)
        print(self.dict)
        print(self.text)
        print(self.number)
        print(self.process_dict)
        
        
        
        
class Type2:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.array =[]
        self.dict = {}
        self.text = "Hello"
        self.number = 0
    
    def change(self):
        while True:
            self.array = [6,7,8,9,10]
            self.dict = {"d":4,"e":5,"f":6}
            self.text = "Goodbye"
            self.number += 1
            print("Type2 changed")
        
    def get_data(self):
        return self.array, self.dict, self.text, self.number
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Type1()
    t.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n\nType1 After Start:")
    t.change()
    t.print()
    t.stop()
    print("\n\nType1 After Finish:")
    t.print()
    print("Type1 stopped")
```

Trying to use a manager according to suggestions in the answer below and changing dict results in a none type which indicates that the shared_var is not shared properly across processes for different objects.

```
import multiprocessing
import time


class Type1:
    def __init__(self, array, dict, text, number) -> None:
        self.array = array
        self.dict = dict
        self.text = text
        self.number = number
        self.process_dict = {}
        self.type2_dict = {}
        self.num = 0
    
    def start(self):
            new_type = Type2(self.array, self.dict, self.text, self.number)
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_type.change, args=(self.dict,))
            self.process_dict[f"type2{self.num}"] = p
            self.type2_dict[f"type2{self.num}"] = new_type
            self.num += 1
            p.start()
        
    def stop(self):
        while len(self.process_dict) > 0:
            _, process = self.process_dict.popitem()
            process.terminate()
            process.join()

    
    def change(self):
        self.array, self.dict, self.text, self.number = self.type2_dict[f"type2{self.num-1}"].get_data()
            
    def print(self):
        print(self.array.value)
        print(self.dict.value)
        print(self.text.value)
        print(self.number.value)
        print(self.process_dict)
        
        
        
        
class Type2:
    def __init__(self, array, dict, text, number) -> None:
        self.array = array
        self.dict = dict
        self.text = text
        self.number = number
    
    def change(self, shared_var):
        while True:
            self.array = [6,7,8,9,10]
            self.text = "Goodbye"
            self.number = 1
            self.dict = shared_var
            # increase each number in the dictionary by 1
            for key in self.dict.keys():
                self.dict[key] += 1
            # shared_var = self.dict
            # print("Type2 changed")
            time.sleep(0.01)
        
    def get_data(self):
        return self.array, self.dict, self.text, self.number
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    array = manager.list([1,2,3,4,5])
    dict = manager.dict({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3})
    text = manager.Value("s", "Hello")
    number = manager.Value("i", 0)
    t = Type1(array, dict, text, number)
    t.start()
    print("\n\nType1 After Start:")
    t.change()
    t.print()
    time.sleep(2)
    t.stop()
    print("\n\nType1 After Finish:")
    t.print()
    print("Type1 stopped")
```

Comment: What did you expect to be different? What output were you expecting? I'm also noting that you said you tried many multiprocessing data sharing and locking techniques, but the code you shared has none of those?

Comment: @Grismar I just edited the post and added that part. I didn't put any/all of those on my code to not clutter it as the different ways involve removing the others. I was curious whether there is a specific way this is generally done

Comment: There's not really a general way to share data between processes. However, it's a hard part of this problem. Two processes can't just share and access objects with changes available to both processes without explicit work to make that possible. My question to you was to establish where to even start with an answer - we could explain why your current code doesn't 'work' but it doesn't work on a few levels, and it would be helpful to know where to start. To share object state between two processes, you could consider using a `Manager` for objects, or `Value` for simpler values.

Comment: @Grismar Thank you for the pointers. I updated the post according to an answer below that uses managers. Do you think using enviroment variables is a decent way of doing it? or is it something i should focus on avoiding?

Comment: Environment variables won't help, as they are copied for each process. So, although it seems like you can use it to pass values to a child process, once the child starts it's operating on its own copies. Don't look for hacks or workarounds, but use libraries, types and functions specifically designed for inter-process communication. It's not hard because someone forgot to add the easy thing - it's hard because there's a lot of work required to keep parallel things in sync. Things like `Manager`  and `Value` *are* the easy solution. (you can also roll your own using ports or pipes)

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing processes cannot communicate directly, but with `multiprocessing.Manager()` you can share several manager variables in the main thread and access them within processes as long as the main thread doesn't end, so I used `process2.join()` in the second process to the main thread does not fall.

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def worker(shared_var, update_var):
    while True:
        # Simulate some work
        if update_var:
            # Send data to the main process through the queue
            current_value = shared_var.value
            new_value = current_value + 1
            shared_var.value = new_value
            time.sleep(0.01)
        else:
            current_value = shared_var.value
            print("Main Process:", current_value)
            time.sleep(1)
                        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a multiprocessing queue
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    
    shared_var = manager.Value('i', 0)

    # Create a multiprocessing process
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(shared_var, True, ))
    process.start()
    
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(shared_var, False, ))
    process2.start()
    process2.join()
```

**In the example, process0 updates the manager variable adding +1 every 0.01 while process2 will only notify the console of the update every 1 second, the result of this is:**

```
Main Process: 2
Main Process: 65
Main Process: 129
Main Process: 192
Main Process: 254
Main Process: 317
Main Process: 381
...
```

**The processes do not interrupt each other and communication is made using the main thread as a bridge.**

Comment: You can invert update_var by switching between True and False when creating processes, the Main Process does not necessarily need to be the reader or writer.

Comment: So that seems to work with numbers, but when using something like dicts it doesn't seem to work propery. I edited the post to add the extra code for the dict with the manager

Comment: I was a bit confused by the code, could you provide a simpler one?

Answer (score 0):

First a general comment: In your first coding attempt you have:

```py
dict = manager.dict({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3})
```

But `dict` is a built-in class whose definition you have just inadvertently overlaid so that if there is any code such as `d = dict(x=1, y=2)`, it will no longer work. Do not redefine built-in functions, classes, etc.

Let's start with your second coding example. You seem to know about the `multiprocessing.Manager`, which is a subclass of `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager` that has defined a set of *managed* classes that you are using, but to no effect. The problem  as mentioned is that your `Type2` instance is executing in a child process *with a copy* of the `Type2` instance that your `Type1` instance `t` is referencing. Therefore, when the `Type2.change` method is invoked it is updating the child process's copy of the`Type2` instance and the `Type2` instance referenced by `t` remains unchanged.

Your`Type2` class is rather simple and Python allows us to create a new, managed class rather easily based on this class. The following code registers with `Type2Manager`, a subclass of `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager`, a new managed type`Type2` and I have simplified your example to demonstrate this. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager) (scroll down and especially read the section **Customized managers**):

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time


class Type2Manager(BaseManager):
    pass

class Type1:
    def __init__(self, manager: Type2Manager) -> None:
        self.manager = manager
        self.array = []
        self.dict = {}
        self.text = ""
        self.number = 0

    def change(self):
        type2 = self.manager.Type2()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=type2.change)
        p.start()
        p.join() # Wait for change to complete
        self.array, self.dict, self.text, self.number = type2.get_data()

    def print(self):
        print("array:", self.array)
        print("dict:", self.dict)
        print("text:", self.text)
        print("number:", self.number)

class Type2:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.array = []
        self.dict = {}
        self.text = "Hello"
        self.number = 0

    def change(self):
        self.array = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        self.dict = {"d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}
        self.text = "Goodbye"
        self.number = 1

    def get_data(self):
        return self.array, self.dict, self.text, self.number

Type2Manager.register('Type2', Type2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Type2Manager() as manager:
        t = Type1(manager)
        # Before calling t.change():
        print("Type1 Before Change:")
        t.print()

        t.change()
        print("\n\nType1 After Change:")
        t.print()
```

Prints:

```None
Type1 Before Change:
array: []
dict: {}
text:
number: 0


Type1 After Change:
array: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
dict: {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
text: Goodbye
number: 1
```